# Postgresql date difference in hours for a calculated column

Tags: postgresql, datediff

Hello I created a view in Postgresl that works except for one column.  I need it subtract reported_date from the previous reported_date and give my answer in hours based on well_id.  I am super lost I would not even mind kicking a few bucks to have a solution.

```
COALESCE(g.Delta_Hours, hours_diff*24 + DATE_PART('hour',p.reported_date,'hh,start'-'hh,end'))  AS Delta_Hours
group by p.well_id,
         p.reported_date,
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`lag()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-window.html#id-1.5.8.28.6.2.2.7.1.1.1) to find the prior reported_date for this well. Then, it's just regular subtraction to get an `INTERVAL` from the 2 dates, `extract(epoch from <interval>)` to get the delta in seconds, and finally `/3600` to convert to hours.

```
testdb=# create table t(well_id integer, reported_date timestamp);
insert into t select 1, '2021-08-01 13:00';
insert into t select 2, '2021-08-01 13:00';
insert into t select 1, '2021-08-01 15:00';
insert into t select 2, '2021-08-01 16:00';
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# SELECT well_id, reported_date,
  extract(epoch from (reported_date -
              (lag(reported_date) over (partition by well_id order by reported_date))
  ))/3600 AS hours_since_last_date_for_this_well
from t;
 well_id |    reported_date    | hours_since_last_date_for_this_well 
---------+---------------------+-------------------------------------
       1 | 2021-08-01 13:00:00 |                                    
       1 | 2021-08-01 15:00:00 |                                   2
       2 | 2021-08-01 13:00:00 |                                    
       2 | 2021-08-01 16:00:00 |                                   3
(4 rows)
```

Given the view definition you have in the comments, the new one would be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.vw_production_with_gauge_time 
AS
SELECT p.well_name, p.well_type, p.well_alias, p.is_active, p.latest_production_time, p.id, p.well_id, p.produced_at, p.oil, p.gas, p.water, p.reported_date, COALESCE(g.gauge_time_local, '6:00am'::character varying) AS gauge_time_local, COALESCE(g.gauge_at_local, p.reported_date::date + '06:00:00'::interval) AS gauge_at_local, COALESCE(g.gauge_at, timezone('UTC'::text, timezone('US/Central'::text, p.reported_date::date + '06:00:00'::interval))) AS gauge_at, p.is_operating, p.hours_on, p.normal_hours_on,
extract(epoch from (p.reported_date -
              (lag(p.reported_date) over (partition by p.well_id order by p.reported_date))
  ))/3600 AS hours_since_last_date_for_this_well
FROM vw_production p LEFT JOIN vw_gauge_times g ON p.reported_date::date = g.gauge_at_local::date AND p.well_id = g.well_id ORDER BY p.reported_date DESC;
```

Comment: I would not be creating a table just adding a column.  This does not seem to work.  I will give you the full code of the view to give you a better idea.

Comment: SELECT p.well_name,
    p.well_type,
    p.well_alias,
    p.is_active,
    p.latest_production_time,
    p.id,
    p.well_id,
    p.produced_at,
    p.oil,
    p.gas,
    p.water,
    p.reported_date,
    COALESCE(g.gauge_time_local, '6:00am'::character varying) AS gauge_time_local,
    COALESCE(g.gauge_at_local, p.reported_date::date + '06:00:00'::interval) AS gauge_at_local,
    COALESCE(g.gauge_at, timezone('UTC'::text, timezone('US/Central'::text, p.reported_date::date + '06:00:00'::interval))) AS gauge_at,
    p.is_operating,
    p.hours_on,

Comment: p.is_operating,
    p.hours_on,
    p.normal_hours_on
   FROM vw_production p
     LEFT JOIN vw_gauge_times g ON p.reported_date::date = g.gauge_at_local::date AND p.well_id = g.well_id
  ORDER BY p.reported_date DESC;

ALTER TABLE public.vw_production_with_gauge_time
    OWNER TO iwell;

GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.vw_production_with_gauge_time TO grafana;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE public.vw_production_with_gauge_time TO driftwood;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.vw_production_with_gauge_time TO iwell;

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.vw_production_with_gauge_time
 AS

Comment: Justin, saying "this does not seem to work" is totally useless. What is the problem? Do you get an error - if so what specifically is it? The result is not what you expect - if so what exactly do you get and what were you expecting.  Further do not place code in comments, instead update the question with it.  Make sure its properly formatted.